# Clicking twice material-ui icon does not change its color to default during tests with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a material-ui navbar with a couple of material-ui icons on it. One of them is a Bookmarks icon. When clicking the icon it becomes blue (`rgb(25, 118, 210)`) and when it is clicked again or somewhere in the page it should become white. This is achieved using a local variable.

```
 <Popover
     ...
     trigger={
       <IconButton classes={{ root: classes.topBarIconButton }}>
          <BookmarksIcon aria-label="bookmarks icon" className={classes.favoriteIcon} />
       </IconButton>
     }
     onEnter={() => setBookmarksOpen(true)}
     onClose={() => setBookmarksOpen(false)}
     >
     <BookmarksList pageTitle={pageTitle} />
 </Popover>
```

I would like to test the behavior (clicking the button twice) now using react-testing-library.
I am able to test successfully that the icon becomes blue once clicked. But once clicked again I keep receiving the blue color and not the expected white or `#fff` or a color in rgb format.

```
test('clicking bookmarks icon once becomes blue, clicking twice becomes white', () => {
      renderWithAllProviders(<Topbar {...props} />, reduxState);
    
      const bookmarksIcon = screen.getByLabelText('bookmarks icon');
      userEvent.click(bookmarksIcon);
      // bookmarks icon color becomes blue on click
      expect(bookmarksIcon).toHaveStyle({ color: 'rgb(25, 118, 210)' }); // this works as expected
      
      userEvent.click(bookmarksIcon);
      // bookmarks icon color becomes white on second click
      expect(bookmarksIcon).toHaveStyle({ color: 'white' }); // this does not work as expected
    
      // 2nd attempt
      // await waitFor(async () => {
      //   // const asyncBookmarksIcon = await screen.findByLabelText('bookmarks icon');
      //   expect(asyncBookmarksIcon).toHaveStyle({ color: 'white' });
      // });
 });
```

I get the following error:

> ● clicking bookmarks icon once becomes blue, clicking twice becomes
> white
>
> ```
> expect(element).toHaveStyle()
>
> - Expected
>
> - color: white;
> + color: rgb(25, 118, 210);
> ```

I tried also using the `waitFor` method but the error becomes even larger in terms of the its output:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
> a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
> function.

included the first error and a big output with printed material ui (probably) native css declarations.

Here is [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clicking-twice-material-ui-icon-does-not-change-its-color-to-default-during-tests-with-react-testing-library-z9c7b?file=/src/Bookmark.js) of the issue. (better download and run it locally cause it freezes for some reason although when run locally works fine).

Any thoughts or recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking this question in the official react-testing-library git hub repository.

and I got the following answer from one of the contributors.

> You run your tests in JSDOM which has not full CSS support

That means that only partial css behavior can be tested.

He mentioned that:

> Anything .`toHaveStyle` has a low confidence depending on how these styles are applied. You should use **visual regression** tests for these types of assertions.

You can find the issue in this [link](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/905) for more information.